# ImportError: No module named etree.ElementTree when running Yahoo BOSS for the first time

Tags: python, python-2.4, yahoo-boss-api

I installed Yahoo BOSS (it's a Python installation that allows you to use their search features). I followed everything perfectly. However, when I run the example to confirm that it works, I get this:

```
$ python ex3.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex3.py", line 16, in ?
    from yos.yql import db
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yos/yql/db.py", line 44, in ?
    from yos.crawl import rest
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yos/crawl/rest.py", line 13, in ?
    import xml2dict
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yos/crawl/xml2dict.py", line 6, in ?
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
ImportError: No module named etree.ElementTree
```

Is there any way to fix this? I did exactly as stated in the documentation and it was installed on a fresh box.

People have suggested that Python 2.5 should be used, but everything currently uses Python 2.4. What should I do to get this Yahoo BOSS to work?

```
Python 2.4.3 (#1, Sep  3 2009, 15:37:37)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)] on linux2
```

Comment: -1: The title is useless.  Please fix the title to mention your actual problem.  Something like "can't import xml.etree" or something that reflects your actual problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Python 2.5 or above: xml.etree.ElementTree was added in 2.5.

http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: How do I use Python 2.5 or above...when everything else right now is built for python 2.4?

Comment: Python 2.4.3 (#1, Sep  3 2009, 15:37:37)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)] on linux2

Comment: CentOS 5 uses 2.4 (just like RHEL5). It looks like elementtree was sourced from the community, so you may be able to add the package "python-elementtree-1.2.6-5.i386.rpm" in yum and get it to work. Otherwise, find a python 2.5 RPM from a reputable source.

Answer (score 0):

A google search reveals that you need to install the [effbot elementtree](http://effbot.org/downloads/#elementtree) Python module.

Comment: Hi, I installed that, but doesn't work.  i guess it's about the Python 2.5.